# Relational database (RDBMS) denormalized data

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database, query-optimization

I believe this question does not address specifically MySQL - which is the database that I'm using -, and it's one about best practices.

Up until now, my problems could be solved by creating tables and querying them (sometimes JOINing here and there). But there is something that I'm doing that doesn't feel right, and it triggers me whenever I need a **denormalized data** alongside my "common" queries.

#### Example Use-case

So that I can express myself better, let's create a superficial scenario where:

- a `user` can buy a `product`, generating a `purchase` (let's ignore the fact that the `purchase` can only have a single `product`);
- and we need to query the `product`s with the total amount of times it has been `purchase`d;

To solve our use-case, we could define a **simple structure** made by:

- `product` table:

  - `product_id` [INT **PK**]
- `user` table:

  - `user_id` [INT **PK**]
- `purchase` table:

  - `purchase_id` [INT **PK**]
  - `product_id` [INT **FK** NOT NULL]
  - `user_id` [INT **FK** NOT NULL]

**Here is where it doesn't feel right**: When we need to retrieve a list of `product`s with the total times it has been purchased, I would create the query:

```
# There are probably faster queries than this to reach the same output
SELECT
    product.product_id,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM purchase
      WHERE purchase.product_id = product.product_id)
FROM
    product
```

My concern origin is that I've read that COUNT does a full table scan, and it scares me to perform the query above when scaled to thousands of products being purchased - even though I've created an INDEX with the `product_id` FK on `purchase` (MySQL does this by default).

---

### Possible solutions

My knowledge with relational databases is pretty shallow, so I'm kind of lost when comparing what are the alternatives (plausible ones) for these kinds of problems. To not say that I haven't done my homework (searching before asking), I've found plausible to:

#### Create Transactions:

When **INSERT**ing a new `purchase`, it must always be inside a transaction that also updates the `product` table with the `purchase.product_id`.

Possible Problems: human error. Someone might manually insert a `purchase` without doing the transaction and BAM - we have an inconsistency.

#### Create Triggers:

Whenever I insert, delete or update some row in some specific table, I would update my `product`s table with a new value (`bought_amount`). So the table would become:

- `product` table:

  - `product_id` [INT PK]
  - `bought_amount` [INT NOT NULL];

Possible problems: are triggers expensive? is there a way that the insertion succeeds but the trigger won't - thus leaving me with an inconsistency?

---

### Question

Updating certain tables to store data that constantly changes is a plausible approach with RDBMSs? Is it safer and - in the long term - more beneficial to just keep joining and counting/summing other occurrences?

I've found a couple of useful questions/answers regarding this matter, but none of them addressed this subject in a wide perspective.
Please take into consideration my ignorance about RDBMS, as I may be suggesting nonsense **Possible solutions**.

Comment: It would make sense to periodically prepare a per-product summary count of previous purchases, then count the purchases that have occurred since the last available summary count, and add the two figures together. This way, you are only having to scan a subset of the purchase data (that subset being the most recent), and after a period of time you can discard the detailed purchase information without affecting the accumulated purchase counts. You could also update the summary count in real-time via a trigger, but a periodic batch job would probably achieve a better balance of performance.

Comment: @Steve, that kind of approach is _so_ last century ("periodic batch job" really? at least a daemon); but it gives operational headaches and software complexity headaches; and a niggling doubt about referential integrity. If this is going to be a heavily-used query, then create a materialised view for the aggregate. Some DBMS's allow for that to be updated on-demand, which gives almost the behaviour you describe, but under the control of the DBMS so it can manage the integrity and volatility.

Comment: @AntC, there is no referential integrity problem in the approach I describe, because the results are always correct according to the real-time state of the database. It simply uses a summary count and then applies any changes since the summary, rather than calculating the whole count from scratch every time. The danger with the indexed view is that it is the writers that pay the price rather than the readers, and more importantly *you can never prune the source data* (because there is no storage of summaries previously prepared, and any pruning of old rows will affect the current count).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Steve, but based on both AntC and GordonLinoff, I was just worrying before the problem had appeared. If it's really a problem that may surface in the future, I'll be sure to try the approach that you've mentioned, with something like updating the summary via triggers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to get a count per key is

```
SELECT product_id, COUNT(*)
FROM purchase
GROUP BY product_id
```

You don't need to mention the `product` table, because all it contains is the key column. Now although that uses `COUNT(*)`, it doesn't need a full table scan for every `product_id` because the SQL engine is smart enough to see the `GROUP BY`.

But this produces a different result to your query: for `product`s that have never been purchased, my query simply won't show them; your query will show the `product_id` with count zero.

Then before you start worrying about implementation and efficiency, what question(s) are you trying to answer? If you want to see all `product`s whether purchased or not, then you must scan the whole `product` table and look up from that to `purchase`. I would go

```
SELECT product_id, count
FROM product
OUTER JOIN (SELECT product_id, COUNT(*) AS count
            FROM purchase
            GROUP BY product_id) AS purch
ON product.product_id = purch.product_id
```

As regards your wider questions (not sure I fully understand them), in the early days SQL was quite inefficient at this sort of joining and aggregating, and schema often were denormalised with repeated columns in multiple tables. SQL engines are now much smarter, so that's not necessary. You might see that old-fashioned practice in older textbooks. I would ignore it and design your schema as normalised as possible.

Comment: Actually, since SQL was originally released as a commercial product in the 1980s, it has been pretty good at joining and aggregating -- it is not like hash joins, reasonable sort algorithms, or indexes are things that were recently invented.  Computers have become much more powerful since then (and algorithms and implementations have improved, of course).

Comment: Thanks @Gordon, but I beg to differ: I've been programming SQL from the early 1980s (on mid-range rather than mainframes). Denormalising schemas for performance reasons was de rigeur. But let's not get bogged down in ancient history: newbies don't need to worry about it these days. (Although quite a bit of tutorial material seems to talk about it, which might be where the question is coming from. SQL textbooks and university lecturers are dreadfully out of touch in my experience.)

Comment: @GordonLinoff: nitpicking: Oracle was the first commercial product to support SQL - and that was releases in 79 ;)

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you and @GordonLinoff, I'm worrying about something that may not even happen in my scenario - where the efficiency of doing counts and sums in queries are worse than just saving some "summary data" in another table. Thank you for your words, it has made me seen that nowadays, RDBMSs are meant to be effective in joins/aggregations. Also, thanks for improving my queries, I will try to normalize everything up until a point where I effectively see a problem, then I might be able to show you guys a problem that DOES exist.

Comment: @AntC - Your first query will do a table scan, or at least an index scan.

Comment: @AntC - I think you need a `LEFT JOIN` and not a "derived table" for the second query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Most of the sort algorithms existed in the '60s.  And the theoretical (and realizable) limit of Order(N logN) was well known back then.  Sort-merge was known then due to needing tape drives for the pieces to merge.  Quicksort (which MySQL uses when it sorts in RAM) existed then.

Comment: @GuilhermeMatuella - "Summary Tables" are important for Data Warehousing where the 'Fact' table(s) has millions of rows and continually grows.  Alas, MySQL does not have any builtin mechanism for such.

Comment: Normalize - yes.  Over-normalize - no.  A simple rule:  Do not normalize any 'continuous' values (dates, times, floats, etc).  Someday you will search by, say, a date range, and performance will go 'down the toilet'.

Answer (score 2):

This query:

```
SELECT p.product_id,
      (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM purchase pu
       WHERE pu.product_id = p.product_id
      )
FROM product p;
```

has to scan both `product` and `purchase`.  I'm not sure why you are emotional about one table scan but not the other.

As for performance, this can take advantage of an index on `purchase(product_id)`.  In MySQL, this will probably be faster than the equivalent (left) join version.

You should not worry about performance of such queries until that becomes an issue.  If you need to increase performance of such a query, first I would ask:  Why?  That is a lot of information being returned -- about all products over all time.  More typically, I would expect someone to care about one product or a period of time or both.  And, those concerns would suggest the development of a datamart.

If performance is an issue, you have many alternatives, such as:

- Defining a data mart to periodically summarize the data into more efficient structures for such queries.
- Adding triggers to the database to summarize the data, if the results are needed in real-time.
- Developing a methodology for maintaining the data that also maintains the summaries, either at the application-level or using stored procedures.

What doesn't "feel right" to you is actually the tremendous strength of a relational database (with a reasonable data model).  You can keep it up-to-date.  And you can query it using a pretty concise language that meets business needs.

Comment: The point is that I was not being emotional about one specific scan, I was just thinking about optimizing one of my queries - that was my main "concern".
Based on both AntC and your answer, I think I'm just really overthinking about this stuff, as I don't even have enough evidence to prove that my problem does exist - just like you've mentioned.
I still think what I'm suggesting makes sense, it's just that my knowledge with relational databases is so superficial, that I can't explain myself using the correct terms. Thank you for your words!

Answer (score 0):

> Possible Problems: human error. Someone might manually insert a purchase without doing the transaction and BAM - we have an inconsistency.

--> Build a Stored Procedure that does both steps in a transaction, then force users to go through that.

> Possible problems: are triggers expensive? is there a way that the insertion succeeds but the trigger won't - thus leaving me with an inconsistency?

Triggers are not too bad.  But, again, I would recommend forcing users through a Stored Procedure that does all the desired steps.

Note:  Instead of Stored Procedures, you could have an application that does the necessary steps; then force users to go through the app and give them *no* direct access to the database.

A database is the "source of truth" on the data.  It is the "persistent" repository for such.  It should not be considered the entire engine for building an application.

As for performance:

- Summing over a million rows may take a noticeable amount of time.
- You can easily do a hundred single-row queries (select/insert/update) per second.
- Please think through numbers like that.